# CHECKPOINT and begin/commit transaction in updating bulk data in Full recovery mode, SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am updating two big tables using a single procedure. I wanted to know how to manage commit transaction/checkpoint so that i will minimize the risk of blow of transaction log. 
Database is SQL server 2005 and recovery mode is full.
Here is my sample code.

```
create procedure procedure_name 
as
declare @CNT INT;
set @CNT=1;

BEGIN trans 
while  @CNT>0
update top (50000) table_a
where condition
set @CNT=@@rowcount

checkpoint
end;

set @cnt=@@rowcount
while  @CNT>0
update top (50000) table_a
where condition
set @CNT=@@rowcount
checkpoint
end;

commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many reasons logging exists is to help you rollback your transactions if you don't want to commit them to disk. Starting a transaction, adding a checkpoint in the middle and then committing I doubt will help your cause.

Please have a good read of these posts which cover your query. Change to a Simple recovery model if you do not need point in time recovery? Perform a full backup after the insert if this is a one off?

[Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

[How to shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/)

[How do checkpoints work](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-do-checkpoints-work-and-what-gets-logged/)

Comment: Thanks Sarin, yes it is one off exercis which i need to perform on Production environment. I doubt if production DBA will agree to change Recovery mode to simple.

Comment: Probably best you have a discussion with your DBAs if you don't have control of the setup\config of your database.